# Do css only if page is unzoomed 75% or more?

Tags: css

How to do css only if page is unzoomed 75% or less? My problem is that the fields are getting too large if the browser unzoom the page with 75 or more%

Comment: Browser zoom was designed as a convenience. It was never supposed to maintain your layout fidelity. This is a micro-optimization with no real use case.

Comment: Your second tag didn't make any sense so I've taken that out, also, when you zoom your browser, it will change the resolution and the media queries apply as well, `%` differs with resolution on each machine... So there won't be any consistent answer for this

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers)

Comment: There should be no functional difference between zooming in and making the window smaller. If there is, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem. Just changed the width form px to %.